# How can I make a door that can only be put on birch wood planks?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been having trouble using commands to make a door that can only be placed on a birch plank. It always says "can be placed on oak wood planks", and I don't know what to do.

How can I make a door that can only be put on a birch wood planks?

Comment: Can you update the question with what commands you've tried?

Comment: So I've attempted this, and I believe it to be an issue with the way bedrock edition handles this restriction in combination with planks. I'm not sure that you will be able to make it be placed on a single type of plank, as they all share the same designator `planks`, but with different data arguments that cannot be inserted into this can_place_on data field when doing /give.

Answer (score 1):

### revision of things we will use(totally optional)

### [data: int]

If you have seen the syntax of the give command, you have probably saw the **[data: int]** part right? Since bedrock edition has some blocks that are only `/give`ed with the **[data: int]** part and *planks* is one, this might be hard (btw birch planks is `/give @p planks 1 2` so [data: int] is 2).

### minecraft:can_place_on

We revised one give input and now I'll do another, **[components: json]**. This is basically NBT tags but for bedrock edition and pretty weaker (honestly bedrock edition is weaker in commands in general). Inside is the two components that help a lot in adventure maps, "minecraft:can_place_on" and "minecraft:can_destory", but we'll (obviously) be revising "can_place_on". It inputs an object containing "blocks" that inputs an array full of blocks.

---

### the answer

we have done a lot of revising (if you decided to read my **totally optional** revision) to get one answer, but the question remains, how to input [data: int] into "can_place_on"... Well, the sad truth is, according to my research, it doesn't work. I have tried "planks 2" and "planks2" and I even tried to find how to but ended up with [https://wiki.bedrock.dev/knowledge/nbt_commands#additional-notes[][1]](https://wiki.bedrock.dev/knowledge/nbt_commands#additional-notes%5B%5D%5B1%5D), I am sorry, and I hope that they will make a way or someone else will find another way...